# jQuery Hide block if td empty

Tags: jquery, hide

I need to hide a table if td is empty (without `a` and `div's`).

sorry guys, my bad

if there is content, there is nothing to hide do not need
but if td is empty  - need to hide the table

```
<table class="klist-actions">
    <tr>
        <td class="klist-actions-goto">
            <a name="forumbottom"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="klist-actions-forum">
            <div class="kmessage-buttons-row">
                <a class="kicon-button kbuttoncomm btn-left" href="#"></a>                      
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="klist-pages-all">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632008/how-can-i-hide-empty-html-table-cells-with-jquery check out this one. it may help you.

Comment: just check if count of `div` and `a` in td is greater than 0. I assume you will always have a div or an a inside it.

Answer (score 4):

This code will hide the table if any of the `td` elements are empty:

```
//select all td elements, iterate through them and check the length of their content
$(".klist-actions td").each(function(i,e){
    if(!$.trim(e.innerHTML).length){
       $(e).parents("table").hide();
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/XJd8t/7/

Comment: I am hiding if the table contains an empty td.

Comment: `$(".klist-actions td").hide();` this however will hide all TDs you are not specifing 1. You need to do your hide on 'e'

Comment: @NetaMeta According to the OP `I need to hide a table`.  The requirements are slightly vague that is why I mentioned it will hide the entire table in the description.

Comment: @KevinBowersox ya, that was what i was missing `I need to hide a table if td is empty`

Comment: @A.Wolff I may have misinterpreted the question, but I assumed that meant hide the table if **any** td is empty.

Comment: then `e.parents('table').hide(); or am i missing something ?

Comment: @NetaMeta Thanks for the suggestion, I like that even better.  I incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: But shouldn't it be: `if(!$.trim(e.innerHTML).length)` instead? Checking if TD is empty

Comment: @A.Wolff  I guess that depends on the specifics of the term `empty`, but I agree nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide tables that have empty `td` elements you can use `.filter()` method:

```
$('table').filter(function(){
    return $('td', this).filter(function() {
       return $.trim(this.innerHTML).length === 0;
    }).length;
}).hide();
```

In case that you want to hide the table that all of it's `td` descendants are empty, you can compare the length of the `td` descendants with empty ones, if all of them are empty hide the table:

```
$('table').filter(function() {
    var $tds = $('td', this);
    return $tds.filter(function() {
       return $.trim(this.innerHTML).length === 0;
    }).length === $tds.length;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will hide any 'table' that has at least one 'td' that doesn't have either an 'a' or 'div'

```
$('table:has(td:not(:has(a div)))').hide();
```

jQuery has a lot of interesting selectors, read about them [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

thx friends ! this code works !!!

```
$('table').filter(function() {
    var $tds = $('td', this);
    return $tds.filter(function() {
       return $.trim(this.innerHTML).length === 0;
    }).length === $tds.length;
}).hide();
```