# How to hide a table cell if a text is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rg933mpd/

HTML:

```
<td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
    <div class="alert info">
        <p>
            <span class="lblInsMsg"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</td>
```

How do I hide the entire TD from view if the span is blank (doesn't have any text in it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide empty html table cells with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632008/how-can-i-hide-empty-html-table-cells-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this using **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.lblInsMsg').text().trim() == '';
}).hide();
```

```css
.hideIt
{
 display: none;
}
  .alert.info {
    border-color: #94dbff;
    color: #0091DC;
}
.alert {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 350px;
}
.alert.info:before {
    background: url(images/info.png) no-repeat center center #bce9ff;
}
.alert:before {
    background: #bbbbbb;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
.alert p {
    margin: 0;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
      <div class="alert info">
        <p>
          <span class="lblInsMsg"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
      <div class="alert info">
        <p>
          <span class="lblInsMsg">ss</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
          <div class="alert info">
            <p>
              <span class="lblInsMsg">dd</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
          <div class="alert info">
            <p>
              <span class="lblInsMsg">ss</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
```

Or

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.lblInsMsg').is(':empty');
}).hide();
```

```css
.hideIt {
  display: none;
}
.alert.info {
  border-color: #94dbff;
  color: #0091DC;
}
.alert {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  color: #6D6D6D;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
}
.alert.info:before {
  background: url(images/info.png) no-repeat center center #bce9ff;
}
.alert:before {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.alert p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
      <div class="alert info">
        <p>
          <span class="lblInsMsg"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
      <div class="alert info">
        <p>
          <span class="lblInsMsg">ss</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
          <div class="alert info">
            <p>
              <span class="lblInsMsg">dd</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;" colspan="3">
          <div class="alert info">
            <p>
              <span class="lblInsMsg">ss</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: I guess I can use a class instead of TD, because there are other TD in the page which I don't want to touch. Thank you.

Comment: I was looking to the `td` itself which I took care of. Thank you though for the path to show me how it's done. Thanks again. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @SiKni8 : glad to help

Answer (score 2):

in your js code, $(this) is referring to the window object.

this code worked for me

```
if ($('.lblInsMsg').is(':empty')) {
    //do something
    $('.lblInsMsg').parent().parent().parent().addClass("hideIt"); //doesn't hide the TD
    alert("empty"); // shows up
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. +1